# Is there a way to customize Reports home page

Tags: reporting

Is there a  way to customize the layout of the "Reports" Home page i.e Reports tab..

I am looking to add "Last Modified By" and "Last Modified Date" as column headers on the report home page?

Currently we have the columns
Action, Name, Schedule, Folder,Created by

Is this even possible or any other available work around.. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, Sneaky Sneaky SFDC. Click on one of the column headers and you should see an option called columns which has both Last modified by and Last modified date
[image]

Comment: voting you up because you took the time to make a screenshot! (and wipe out the org details :-))))

Comment: @guy lol I always do that with my screenshots :). Thanks though.

Comment: Thank you so much.. My bad i should have seen it more closely... Is this change specific to each user.. ie. its applies at org level or each user level..i believe the settings apply to each user..

Comment: it's user specific indeed..

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and very easy.....if you know how!

1. Hover over the Created By column header (or any other)
2. Click the triangle icon appearing on the right
3. Go to "columns" and add any additional column you need